# Configure MyBatis configuration file for caching

Tags: hibernate, mybatis

How to configure MyBatis caching that is Similar to Hibernate query level cache or Cache provider in configuration file

Comment: Please check the MyBatis docs.you might need to specify the localCacheScope setting in your xml file.http://www.mybatis.org/core/configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put  `<cache/>` at the top of the xml file just after xml declarations.
This works fine for me.